# ON/OFF toggle as a custom view field

Tags: 7, views, entities, ajax

I have a table view output of node data. The node type has a list field called status.
Status is set to accept a single value. It has the following option to select from:

```
Inactive
Active
Submitted
Approved
```

They work in pairs. When a node is created it's Inactive by default. Someone reviews it and sets it to Active. Upon further work it is set to Submitted and eventually someone else will set it to Approved.

What I am tasked with is creating a toggle button against each row of the table output 
containing **[Inactive|Active]** or **[Submitted|Approved]** which a user can simply click on and change it's status rather than go to the actual nodes' edit page.

I'm interested in ideas on how I can accomplish this or perhaps if there is a module that fully or partially does this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the [Editable Fields](https://drupal.org/project/editablefields) module. It let you edit any CCK field on node/view display page, and it changes field values on the fly using AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

For Drupal 8 You have to use Toogle Editable Fields https://www.drupal.org/project/toggle_editable_fields

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using the flag and rules modules.
Set a role named "moderator". Moderator users can flag the content as active. Then other role ("super moderator" for example) can flag the content as approved/ submitted. 
Configure a rule to publish the content when it's flagged as approved.
You can also create views accessible only to specific roles where they can view the nodes flagged as inactive/ active/ submitted/ or approved.
In order to create a toggle button - try this tutorial - http://www.wdtutorials.com/2011/10/18/drupal-7-how-create-do-list-flag-module.
You can also try the Workflow module.